# Time-based notification in Oreo

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

I am working on a task scheduling app that reminds me of a task at a certain time. I used to implement this with `getSystemService(AlarmManager.class).set(RTC_WAKEUP, millis, pendingIntent);`. Then a `IntentService` gets started later and shows a notification.

But in Android Oreo my `IntentService` simply doesn't get called at all. I noticed the massive discussion about the [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) and how you should migrate from `AlarmManager` to `JobScheduler`, but nobody mentions how `JobScheduler` can start a job based on RTC.

What my `IntentService` does besides showing a notification is nothing more than setting the task as "notified" or "done", which I think is incomparable to the heavy tasks like synchronizing big amount of data over network that the `JobScheduler` was introduced for.

What is the best practice in Android Oreo to implement time-based notifications?

Comment: suggestion is to use Broadcast recievers . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815899/localnotification-with-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-not-firing-up-in-andro

Comment: use firebase job dispatcher

Comment: @notTdar could you give more information on how Firebase JobDispatcher can be used to schedule a task with RTC?

Comment: Jobs automatically takes care of waking your device, but if you want to go for exact time then use setAlarmClock and setExactWhileInIdle

Answer (score 1):

I am taking @balu-sangem 's solution:

- Replace `PendingIntent.getService()` with
  `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`
- Replace `IntentService` with `BroadcastReceiver`