# Notifications in Android Oreo

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-workmanager

First of all, I know this has been asked several times before, however I've yet to find a working solution so I thought about asking anyway.

In my app I'm using a `AlarmManager` to trigger a notification at a specific moment. It works all fine in Nougat and lower, however it never triggers when tested on Oreo (and suppose it wouldn't work on Pie either).

I've tried all sorts of things, like using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`. Which according to other users should work on Oreo but it didn't work for me. I also found about WorkManager, however people recommended not to use it in production apps since it's still in beta and apparently it's also not recommended if you need the task to run at a really specific time.

I would show my code however it's just a simple `AlarmManager` with a `BroadcastReceiver` like any other example you might find on the internet.

This is a really app breaking "bug" for me and at this point I don't know what to do. Thanks.

**EDIT**: The `AlarmManager` does work in Android Oreo and above, the problem was with the notifications. Starting with Oreo you need to set up a `NotificationChannel`, otherwise the notifications are never going to show up. That's it.

Comment: does this happen on all devices or is it specific to e.g. Samsung phones?

Comment: @shelll I've tried it in my Huawei phone and also in AVD's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key point is that you have to use explicit broadcasts in case of Oreo.

[Discussion with solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815899/localnotification-with-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-not-firing-up-in-andro).

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).

Comment: thanks, however I was already working with explicit broadcasts. The answer to my problem was in the link you gave though. The problem was with the notifications rather than the AlarmManager.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may work. I was also facing same issue as yours and this code works fine for me.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(d.getTime(), pendingIntent), pendingIntent);
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, d.getTime(), pendingIntent);
else
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, d.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

setAlarmClock() method works in most of each and every conditions. Even if device is in [Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby), this method will work.

You can know more about `setAlarmClock()` method from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).